# Dúvida sobre Criteria do Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Eu estou tentando fazer um sistema para ordem de serviço só para eu treinar. Nas ordens de serviço eu posso ter varias categorias. E minha duvida esta na hora de exibir, por exemplo, um ranking das categorias mais usadas por um período x usando o *criteria* do *hibernate*. Algo que o resultado saísse organizado assim:

Categoria A - 10 vezes 
Categoria B - 8 vezes 
 
Categoria C - 5 vezes

**O que eu posso utilizar nesse caso?**

As classes resumidamente estão mapeadas assim

**Classe ordemServico**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordem_servico")
public class OrdemServico extends GenericModel {

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "data_os", nullable = false)
private Date dataOS;   

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinTable(name = "os_categoria", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_os"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_categoria"))
private List<Categoria> categorias;     
}
```

**Classe Categoria**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria_os")
public class Categoria extends GenericModel {
@Column(name = "nome_cat", nullable = false, length = 40)

@NotBlank
private String nome;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

}
```

Comment: Explicar melhor a regra do negócio ai. Está faltando um campo para o período também.

Comment: @MatheusSilva Desculpe a demora. Tipo eu tenho ordens de servico que podem ter varias categorias e eu queria fazer tipo um top 10 de categorias mais utilizadas

Comment: De cada ordem de serviço ou de todas?

Comment: @MatheusSilva de todas as categorias de serviço. Tipo um ranking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma que pensei para resolver isso foi assim, deve ter melhores k

Criar uma tabela que representa a ligação ManyToMany:

```
@Entity
public class OrdemServicoCategoria {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idOsCategoria;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idOrdem")
private OrdemServico os;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="nome")
private Categoria categoria; //Atributo nome vira ID na tabela categoria
//...Outros métodos
}
```

Em ordem serviço tem o atributo

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "os", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<OrdemServicoCategoria> osCategorias = new ArrayList<OrdemServicoCategoria>();
```

Uma classe Ranking não persistente, apenas para obter os dados:

```
public class Ranking {

private Categoria categoria;
private Long vezes; 


public Ranking(Categoria categoria, Long vezes) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
    this.vezes = vezes;     
}

//Outros métodos
}
```

O método do DAO para recuperar fica assim:

```
public List<Ranking> getRanking() {
        String consulta = "select new org.autocomplete.models.Ranking(os_cat.categoria, COUNT(idOsCategoria))"
                + " FROM OrdemServicoCategoria os_cat group by os_cat.categoria";
        TypedQuery<Ranking> query = manager.createQuery(consulta, Ranking.class);       
        return query.getResultList();       
    }
```

No caso, não usei Criteria, não sei qual a sua necessidade de usar criteria, com criteria ficaria algo como está nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491796/hibernate-group-by-criteria-object, mas não consegui resolver com isso k

Você pode colocar a data na tabela intermediária e usar a cláusula where para os períodos.